# Authentication fails when connecting to Dockerized instance of MongoDB

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, docker, mongodb

I have been having quite a time connecting to a Dockerized instance of MongoDB. I was able to configure a MongoDB container per [these instructions](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) on my local development machine, but the same steps don't seem to work in production.

My exact steps to create, run and connect to the container:

1. Create and run the container

   `docker run --name prod-mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo --auth`
2. Added the initial user:

   `docker exec -it prod-mongo mongo admin`

   `db.createUser({user:'skipper', pwd:'skipperspassword', roles:[{role:'userAdminAnyDatabase',db:'admin'}] });`
3. Successfully connected to Docker container from another Mongo container:

   `docker run -it --rm --link prod-mongo:mongo mongo mongo -u skipper -p --authenticationDatabase admin prod-mongo/skippers-apps`
4. **Unsuccessfully** connected to Docker container from Docker host:
   `mongo skippers-apps --authenticationDatabase admin -u skipper -p`

It's that last step that I'm concerned with. It works in my local development environment, but not production.

Development Environment

- Operating System: Mac OS El Capitan
- Kernel Version 15.6.0
- MongoDB Shell Version: 3.2.7
- Docker Version: 1.12.3

Production Environment

- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Kernel Version: 4.4.0
- MongoDB Shell Version: 2.6.10
- Docker Version: 1.12.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure why the version of MongoDB I was using previously (2.6.10) wasn't playing well with Docker, I was able to solve the problem by upgrading the version of the MongoDB client.

I would be curious to know the exact reason that a 2.6.10 client couldn't connect to the MongoDB server in the default Docker MongoDB image.

**Solution**: upgraded the MongoDB client from 2.6.10 to 3.2.11